# Symfony2 randomly getting Forbidden error

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, permission-denied

I have an AcmeUserBundle that extends FOSUserBundle and I am able to login fine. I have another AcmeTestBundle where I display some information. 
After I login I have a page with links like these:

```
 http://localhost/smf/web/app_dev.php/test/view/1
 http://localhost/smf/web/app_dev.php/test/view/2
 http://localhost/smf/web/app_dev.php/test/view/3
 ...
```

They all display the same page with just different info for the specific id. After login at first everything works fine, but after a few  clicks on the same link I get:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /smf/web/app_dev.php/test/view/2 on this server.
```

When I clear the cache and wait a about a minute, everything goes back to normal.
It seems really weird.

My route looks like this:

```
acme_test_view:
    path:     /test/view/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeTestBundle:Default:view, id: null }
    requirements:
      id: \d+
    methods: [GET]
```

"id" by default is null because if no ID is provided I have to display the first entry from the db along with the links for all others.

In security.yml I`ve set:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/test/, role: ROLE_USER}
```

I am not sure if my problem is in the user settings, the routing or something completely different. 
Any ideas what I am doing wrong ?

Edit: 
Simplified version of my action looks like this:

```
public function viewAction( $id = null) 
{
   $item = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository("AcmeTestBundle:Item")
            ->find($id);
   return $this->render("AcmeTestBundle:Default:view.html.twig", array("item" => $item));
}
```

Just getting data and passing it to the template. Nothing special.

Comment: Do you check user access or role or something similar in you `viewAction`? It might help if you post the action code.

Comment: I just added some of the code in my action, I don`t do anything special in there

Comment: What does the profiler (bottom toolbar) tell you? It will help you figure out if you're being recognized as a user or not in those particular cases.

Comment: When the profiler is there it says that I am logged in as the same use as I should be.
 
When I get the Forbidden error, no other info is displayed on the screen. 

Now is see that sometimes this happens on other pages too, like the login page

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Problem is, that you are not logged in.
You've created a secured area for users with the role `ROLE_USER`. If you are not logged in, this will cause the 403 Error.

In addition to that, you should declare another area to be accessable via annonymous. Maybe your login-Action is also behind the firewall, so that you cannot access the login Form.

Please have a look at http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html and read the section "Avoid common Pitfalls".

Regards!